# What is the usage difference between dilemma and quandary

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

> Between dilemma and quandary, what are the various denotations and connotations.

- *A dilemma is a difficult choice, not just any difficulty or problem*.

The dictionaries put them as synonyms.

- I'm in a [quandary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quandary) about whether I should try to repair my stereo or buy a new one
- I don't know what to do; it's a real [dilemma](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma).

If you're at the mall choosing between red, green or blue socks, it is dilemma or quandary.

It's so confusing.

Comment: _Dilemma_ is a special case with two horns (i.e, two opposed premises to reconcile or choices to make), while _quandary_ is just a general term made up from the Latin QU- question words for _what, where, why, when,_ etc. (PIE *kw- changed to Germanic *hw- via Grimm's Law, but it stayed the same in Latin, where it was spelled QU-).

Comment: It seems like _quandary_ is usually used to refer to the person's mental state, while _dilemma_ refers to the situation causing it.

Comment: That's certainly one way to use them. But not everybody may make that distinction.

Comment: ... Though modern usage allows 'dilemma' to be used more generally:  an argument presenting two or more equally conclusive alternatives against an opponent / a difficult or persistent problem <unemployment … the great central dilemma of our advancing technology  [your M-W reference].

Comment: > If on the horns of a dilemma...

> Remember- Dilemma (from Greek dilemma "two" + lemma premise")
> is for "double proposition."

Comment: The answer that simplified it for me is"@Barmar's: It seems like quandary is usually used to refer to the person's mental state, while dilemma refers to the situation causing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *dilemma* is a choice between several options that are equally unfavourable.

A *quandary* is the state of being uncertain as to what you should do.

But *dilemma* is also used of the state of having a dilemma to solve, while *quandary* is also used of the cause of the *quandary*, so there is certainly a large overlap between these two.

*Dilemma* is still used by some to refer only two options (the original meaning) or at least where there are known options (as opposed to just "I don't know what to do about this"). Some people though use it more loosely to be more fully synonymous with *quandary*.

> If you're at the mall choosing between red, green or blue socks, it is dilemma or quandary.

It would be an example of hyperbole to describe it as either. If you aren't a stickler for the dilemma = 2 things rule, then either is equally good (if over the top), otherwise it's only a quandary.

While they can be used interchangeably (hence the dictionaries listing them as synonyms as you say), *dilemma* does more often refer to the choice and *quandary* the mental and moral state of having to make it, which gives *dilemma* a slightly greater nuance of the difficulty faced, *quandary* a slightly greater nuance of the emotional response to it.

Comment: This is the best of the answers given, IMO. Subjectively, it amounts to a difference between being puzzled and being conflicted.

Answer (score 2):

Per the definitions you link to, a *quandary* is:

> a situation in which you are confused about what to do

This could be any sort of situation where the "best" choice is not obvious.

A *dilemma* is:

> a situation in which you have to make a difficult choice

The intent here is that every option available to you is undesirable, but you nevertheless have to choose.

Often, when you have a dilemma, it is also a quandary, because which of the bad choices is "least bad" is not at all obvious and it is difficult to decide what to do.  (This is not always the case, though; sometimes you might easily choose a "known to be about X bad" over an "I have no idea how bad it could get" option.)

On the other hand, when you have a *quandary*, it is entirely possible to be picking from a set of choices that are entirely good in different ways, or that balance good and bad aspects, or that are a relatively meaningless set of choices that you just can't decide between.

Picking socks may constitute a *quandary* if you simply can't determine which set of socks will best match your outfit, but it is definitely NOT a *dilemma*, where no matter what socks you pick your life will be difficult and the only question is how it will become difficult.

Comment: There are other definitions given there.

Comment: +1,I agree, choosing between red or blue socks, that's not really a dilemma.